# How to merge more than one list having objects into one list with sum of one of the elements of the list in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects like:

```
var list = new List<someUi>
            {
               {Name="Arjun", Salary=100, Div="A"},
               {Name="Dani", Salary=50, Div="B"},
               {Name="Nick", Salary=75, Div="C"},
               {Name="Arjun", Salary=55, Div="A"},
               {Name="Dani", Salary=10, Div="B"}
            }
```

Now I want to merge the list based one **Name** `(GroupBy Name)` and want to total the Salary.

so, My expected output is like this:

```
var list = new List<someUi>
            {
               {Name="Arjun", Salary=155, Div="A"},
               {Name="Dani", Salary=60, Div="B"},
               {Name="Nick", Salary=75, Div="C"}
            }
```

How can I do that using C# or LINQ.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The specification is not complete. What do you want if you also have a `{Name="Arjun", Salary=100, Div="B"},`? Do you want only one Arjun in the end result with his total salary, and what do you want as Div? Or do you want two Arjuns: one with Div A and one with Div B?

Comment: assume Div for unique name is same. but there is more than one field like salary for doing Sum. So, The answer of Nima Talebi is worked for me.

Comment: I agree with @HaraldCoppoolse and because of that I mentioned in my answer you need to group by multiple properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var list = new List<someUi>()
{
    new someUi() {Name = "Arjun", Salary = 100, Div = "A"},
    new someUi() {Name = "Dani", Salary = 50, Div = "B"},
    new someUi() {Name = "Nick", Salary = 75, Div = "C"},
    new someUi() {Name = "Arjun", Salary = 55, Div = "A"},
    new someUi() {Name = "Dani", Salary = 10, Div = "B"}
};

var grouped = list.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x=> new someUi { Name=x.Key,Salary = x.Sum(x=>x.Salary),Div = x.First().Div}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your expected result you may need to group by the list based on both `Div` and `Name`, So try this one:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(g => new {g.Name, g.Div})
         .Select(s => new someUi {
          Name = s.Key.Name, 
          Div = s.Key.Div,
          Salary = s.Sum(t => t.Salary)
       }).ToList();
```